# How can a google-chart be created within a new element I've just appended using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

For context, I'm trying to build a page that displays a google chart for all active sports games that day. A data feed will inform how many there are (in my below example, 3 games going on.) From there, I would like to loop through the set of games, create a div for each one using jQuery, and then place a google chart into each div. Here's what I wrote:

This would come from a data feed:

```
var activeGames = 3;
```

Cycle through active games, build a chart for each one

```
for (i = 0; i < activeGames; i++){

  $('.chartContainer').append("<div id='game'></div>");

  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Team A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Team B');

  data.addRows([1,1]);
    //chart data redacted, would come from data feed


  var options = {
    //chart options redacted, irrelevant
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('game'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Relevant basics:

- linked to jQuery in HTML appropriately
- My HTML file is basically just a div for the chartContainer class

The chart displays fine if I create **div id='g1'** in an html file, but for some reason no charts display when the div is created by jquery, even though the divs DO get created.

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE: Here's what worked:

Load google charts package

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Call Function, the for loop goes within:

```
function drawChart() {

    var activeGames = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < activeGames; i++){
        $('.container').append("<div id='g" + i + "'></div>");

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Team A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
    data.addRows([1,1]]); //redacted the rest
    var options = {};//redacted

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('g'+ i));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

};

Comment: Part of the problem is probably related to the fact that you're creating multiple `div`s with the same `id`.  `id` should be unique to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load google first, wait for the `callback`, then draw the charts...

`google.charts.load` only needs to be called once per page load

no need to `load` for each chart

since you're creating a new `<div>` for each chart,
create the div and pass it to the chart's constructor
no need to assign an `id`, which would need to be unique anyway

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawCharts() {
  var activeGames = 3;

  for (i = 0; i < activeGames; i++){

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Team A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Team B');
    data.addRow([1,1]);

    var options = {
    };

    var container = document.createElement('div');
    $('.chartContainer').append(container);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chartContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that the `id` should be unique to the page.  So when creating the `div`, you should make it unique:

```
$('.chartContainer').append("<div id='game" + i + "'></div>");
```

Then, when selecting the `div`, select the correct `div`:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('game' + i));
```

Comment: Thank you both. I got it to work using a combination of your answers.